# Display median of participants' moving average in time series plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with time series data in R and quite new to it. I have data (just over 24hrs) from 18 participants, for which I have calculated a centred moving average. The desired plot thus shows how my y variable changes across time for each participant. Here is a reproducible code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# Create participants data
participants <- data.frame(id = 1:18,
                           activity_level = round(runif(18, min = 1, max = 10), 2))

# Create timestamps for each participant
start_times <- as.POSIXct(c("2022-12-16 14:00:03", "2022-12-16 10:23:04", "2022-12-16 12:45:00",
                            "2022-12-16 19:10:45", "2022-12-16 18:30:00", "2022-12-16 13:15:00",
                            "2022-12-16 16:30:00", "2022-12-16 21:00:00", "2022-12-16 17:30:00",
                            "2022-12-16 12:00:00", "2022-12-16 14:30:00", "2022-12-16 11:00:00",
                            "2022-12-16 08:00:00", "2022-12-17 00:30:00", "2022-12-16 16:45:00",
                            "2022-12-17 08:00:00", "2022-12-17 12:00:00", "2022-12-17 06:30:00"))

end_times <- start_times + as.difftime(sample(1200:36000, 18, replace = TRUE), units = "secs")

# Create the dataframe
df <- data.table(participant = integer(),
                 timestamp = as.POSIXct(character()),
                 activity_level = numeric(),
                 moving_average = numeric())

# Fill the dataframe with data for each participant
for (i in 1:18) {
  participant_data <- data.table(participant = rep(i, length(seq(from = start_times[i], to = end_times[i], by = "10 sec"))),
                                 timestamp = seq(from = start_times[i], to = end_times[i], by = "10 sec"),
                                 activity_level = round(runif(length(seq(from = start_times[i], to = end_times[i], by = "10 sec"))), 2))
  participant_data[, moving_average := frollmean(activity_level, n = 360, align = "center", na.rm =TRUE)]
  df <- rbind(df, participant_data)
}
```

When I plot the moving averages per participant:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(timestamp, moving_average)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = as.factor(participant))) +
  labs(y = "Activity levels", x = "Time") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = as.POSIXct(c("2022-12-16 10:00:00", "2022-12-17 14:00:00"), tz = 'UTC'), 
                   date_labels = "%H:00", expand = c(0, 0))
```

I get this plot:

[image: plot 1]

Now I would like to add a line to this plot, showing the median of these moving averages + interquartile range lines. I tried by adding:

```
stat_summary(fun.data ="median", geom = "line")
```

and I get:

[image: plot 2]

I think the problem is the following: although the sampling rate of activity is the same, and the duration is 24 hours for all, participants have different timestamps - i.e. started the experiment at different times.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I ended up making a reproducible copy of my code and edited my original question. I hope this clarifies what my issues are. Sorry about the image links - I am still trying to understand how to edit that!

Comment: Can you elaborate what's wrong with the result you got, i.e. how it differs from what you expected?